# Cats IO - Make tail recursive call inside flatmap

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm trying to make my function which returns an IO tail recursive but it does not compile because I'm using it inside flatMap. I know there are things built for this purpose such as tailRec but I'm looking for some guidance on how to use them. Here's the sample code.

```
    import cats.effect.IO
    import scala.annotation.tailrec

    def process(since: Option[String]): IO[Seq[String]] = {

      @tailrec
      def go(startIndex: Int): IO[(Int, Seq[String])] = {

        val program = since match {
          case Some(s) =>
            for {
              r <- fetchResponse(s, startIndex)
              size = r.size
              ss = r.data
              _ <- writeResponse(ss)

            } yield (size,  r)
          case None => IO((0, Seq.empty[String]))
        }

        program.flatMap { case (size, _) =>
          if (startIndex <= size) go( startIndex + size)
          else IO((0, Seq.empty))
        }
      }

      go(0).map(o => o._2)
    }

    case class Response(size: Int, data: Seq[String])

    def fetchResponse(s: String, i: Int): IO[Response] = ???

    def writeResponse(r: Seq[String]): IO[Int] = ???
```

Comment: Which part of the whole construction is supposed to be tail-recursive? What did you intend to do with a `@tailrec` annotation on a `val`?

Comment: Apologies. Go is supposed to be recursive. Fixed the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: don't worry about it.

The way that cats constructs and executes `IO` instances, especially with `flatMap` is pretty stack-safe, [as described here](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#stack-safety).

When you do `x.flatMap(f)`, `f` is not executed immediately within the same stack. It is executed later by cats in a way that essentially implements tail recursion internally. As a simplified example, you can try running:

```
def calculate(start: Int, end: Int): IO[Int] = {
  IO(start).flatMap { x =>
    if (x == end) IO(x) else calculate(start + 1, end)
  }
}

calculate(0, 10000000).flatMap(x => IO(println(x))).unsafeRunSync()
```

Which is essentially the same as what you are doing, and it prints out `10000000` just fine.

Comment: This seems to die on me: `def f(x: Int): IO[Int] = IO.whenA (x % 1234 == 0) { IO(println(x)) } *> (if (x != 0) (f(x - 1)) else IO(0))` for `f(100000).unsafeRunSync()`. Is it different somehow?

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/749) makes me worry about not worrying about it.